# Why can I not select/target this anchor by its ID?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

[image: For some reason neither CSS nor jQuery have any affect on this anchor when trying to select it by its ID]

Is there something obviously wrong that I'm just not seeing here?

Comment: Get rid of the `#` in the id attribute: `<a id="addrow">`

Comment: Note that the `#` in your selector (`$('#addrow')`) is actually a special character, meaning "select by the following characters on the `id`". So the selector is looking for an element whose `id` is `addrow`, which doesn't exist.

Comment: @JohnConde I **knew** it was going to be one of these things. Too many hours in front of the computer today, and maybe too much jQuery. ;) Thanks for the fresh eyes!

Comment: Be awesome and keep it like that, you can then call it like that : `$('#\\#test')`. Joking, do what John say.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`#` is a special character / operator in CSS selectors. It's not really meant to be part of the `id` attribute's value.

```
<a id="addrow">
```

```
$('#addrow')
```

Granted, it is possible to keep the `#` in the attribute, but you'll have to [escape the character](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/faq/how-do-i-select-an-element-by-an-id-that-has-characters-used-in-css-notation/) in the selector:

```
$('#\\#addrow')
```